# Have Chrome pretend to be an iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, google-chrome

I am sure that I have seen someone impersonate iPad Safari in Chrome. Do you know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers identify themselves by the 'user-agent' string in HTTP request header

You can change it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US&gl=US

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tutorial that shows you how to accomplish this.  You simply change the user agent to be the same as that of ipad safari

[Get Ipad interface using Chrome user agent string](http://www.guidingtech.com/2803/get-ipad-interface-chrome-user-agent-string/)

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think this mostly has to do with the `user-agent` string that the browser sends. When testing access scenarios it is useful to impersonate other browsers such as Safari or Mobile Safari from a Windows PC. This can be done with Chrome using the following syntax when launching the app. This example impersonates the mobile safari browser on an iPhone. Try this -

```
chrome.exe --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3"
```

There are many “user-agent” strings that can be added to this syntax and a google search should discover the correct one required.

This is very useful during testing when one wants to know how the back-end systems behave when requests from different browsers come in.